# why different result in c++ and java version?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, imagefilter

I implemented Java image filter code in c++ ndk but the results differ.
The value in both is 70.

Java version :

```
public Bitmap applyContrastEffect(Bitmap src, double value) {
    // image size
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();
    // create output bitmap
    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
    // color information
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;
    // get contrast value
    double contrast = Math.pow((100 + value) / 100, 2);
    // scan through all pixels
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            // get pixel color
            pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            // apply filter contrast for every channel R, G, B
            R = Color.red(pixel);
            R = (int) (((((R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if (R < 0) {
                R = 0;
            } else if (R > 255) {
                R = 255;
            }

            G = Color.red(pixel);
            G = (int) (((((G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if (G < 0) {
                G = 0;
            } else if (G > 255) {
                G = 255;
            }

            B = Color.red(pixel);
            B = (int) (((((B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
            if (B < 0) {
                B = 0;
            } else if (B > 255) {
                B = 255;
            }
            int val = Color.argb(A, R, G, B);
            // set new pixel color to output bitmap
            bmOut.setPixel(x, y, val);
        }
    }

    // return final image
    return bmOut;
}
```

c++ version :

```
int* ContrastFilter::procImage() {
double value = 70;
double contrast = pow((100 + value) / 100, 2);
int A, R, G, B;

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
    //__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "Contrast Filter","The before color is %d", this->pixels[i]);
    Color color(this->pixels[i]);
    A = color.alpha();

    R = color.R();
    R = (int) (((((R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
    if (R < 0) {
        R = 0;
    } else if (R > 255) {
        R = 255;
    }

    G = color.G();
    G = (int) (((((G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
    if (G < 0) {
        G = 0;
    } else if (G > 255) {
        G = 255;
    }
    B = color.B();
    B = (int) (((((B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
    if (B < 0) {
        B = 0;
    } else if (B > 255) {
        B = 255;
    }

    this->pixels[i] = ARGB2Color(A, R, G, B);
}

return this->pixels;
```

}

Java c++ interface:

```
public static Bitmap changeToContrast(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        int height = bitmap.getHeight();
        Bitmap returnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, bitmap.getConfig());
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        int[] returnPixels = NativeFilterFunc.contrastFilter(pixels, width,
                height);
        returnBitmap.setPixels(returnPixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        return returnBitmap;

    }
```

Java result :

[image]

c++ result :

[image]

I can't understand why the result is different.
When I debug, I see some pixel values are different, but why does this happen when the calculation formula is the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
R = Color.red(pixel);
...
G = Color.red(pixel);
...
B = Color.red(pixel);
```

You are taking the red value for each color in your Java code. You probably want to adjust that to take the correct value instead like so:

```
R = Color.red(pixel);
...
G = Color.green(pixel);
...
B = Color.blue(pixel);
```

As a sidenote: According to Java conventions, variable names should start with a *lower* case letter.

Comment: opps ... goofs.banal mistake